# Populate model of model on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been digging into this for a while now, found no answer valid and nothing like I want to do on Google so I've come here to ask this question.

How do you populate a Schema like this?

```
var category_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {required: true, type: String},
  parent: {type: Number, ref: 'Category' },
  categories: [ {type: Number, ref: 'Category'} ]
});
```

What I'm doing right now is this:

```
Category.find({parent: null}).populate({path: 'categories', model: 'Category'}).exec(function(err, categories) {
```

But doing a console.log on categories would show on the console:

```
[ { __v: 2,
    _id: 18,
    name: 'Categoria',
    parent: null,
    categories:
     [ { __v: 1,
         _id: 19,
         name: 'Children',
         parent: 18,
         categories: [Object] }, // <= THIS SHOULD HAVE ACTUAL CATEGORIES
       { _id: 20, name: 'Children 2', parent: 18, __v: 0, categories: [] } ] } ]
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

This is what I'm using to show em up

```
ul.list-group
  if inputs == true
    li.list-group-item
      .radio
        label
          input(type='radio', class='radio', name='parent_id' value='0')
          = 'No category'
  mixin make_list(categories, edit)
    each category in categories
      li.list-group-item
        .radio
          if inputs == true
            input(type='radio', name='parent_id', value='#{category._id}')
          = category.name
  if categories.length
    each category in categories
      li.list-group-item
        .radio
          label
            if inputs == true
              input(type='radio', name='parent_id', value='#{category._id}')
            = category.name
      if category.categories.length
        ul
          +make_list(category.categories, edit)
```

Since I had no answers, I started digging by myself on how to do this...

Now, this might not be the best way to do it, but oh well;

```
category_schema.static('make_tree', function(callback) {
  Category.find(function(err, categories) {
    var parents_array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      var category = categories[i];
      if (category.parent == null || category.categories.length) {
        categories[i].categories = [];
        parents_array.push(categories[i]);
      }
    }

    for(var x = parents_array.length -1; x >= 0; x--) {
      for(var y = 0; y < categories.length; y++) {
        if (categories[y].parent === parents_array[x]._id) {
          console.log('adding ' + categories[y].name + ' to ' + parents_array[x].name);
          parents_array[x].categories.push(categories[y]);
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(parents_array);
    // Remove parents which have parents. 
    for(var i = parents_array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (parents_array[i].parent) {
        parents_array.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    callback(parents_array);
  });
});
```

Thing is..., I still get this when I do a console log:

```
PARENTS ARRAY NOW
[ { __v: 1,
    _id: 23,
    name: 'Categoria',
    parent: null,
    categories: [ { parent: 23, name: 'Hijo', _id: 24, __v: 2, categories: [Object] } ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be experiencing a vagary of the node console. What happens if you do `console.log(categories[0].categories)`? (assuming `categories` is the name of that fisrt object.

Comment: So those are references to the categories in the db. I am not a mongoose, but it looks like you'll just have to make additional method calls for those categories.